# Extracting text with jsoup out of a table with breaks

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

Some knows how I can extract those texts with Jsoup?

```
<TR> 
    <TD bgColor=#ffa55c><B> 
      The first text I want.      </B><BR>
      <BR>
      The second text I want      <BR>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

I can get the first one with:

```
Element element = doc.select("tr td:eq(1) b").get(1);
element.text();
```

But I don't get the second one :(

Comment: What is .get(1), I don't see Element type having any method such as get() (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your table cell tag `TD` to make the HTML well formed

```
<table>
<TR> 
    <TD bgColor=#ffa55c><B> 
      The first text I want.      </B><BR>
      <BR>
      </TD><TD> <!-- add this -->
      The second text I want      <BR>
    </TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

otherwise JSoup will consider the first & second cell as one and `get` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, then you can simple use

```
Element element = doc.select("td").get(2);
```

Comment: I agree with but unfortunately I am not able to change the html code :/ I need to work with this ugly thing <.<

Answer (score 1):

Using the table data you gave us, you can easily get all the text in one fell swoop:

```
String html = "<TR><TD bgColor=#ffa55c><B>The first text I want.</B><BR><BR>The second text I want<BR></TD></TR>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println("test: " + doc.text());
```

With the output:

```
test: The first text I want. The second text I want
```

I think you need to restrict your select to the TR and ignore everything after it, so make it something like

```
// get the TRs
Elements elements = doc.select("tr");

// iterate through the TRs
for (Element element: elements){
    System.out.println(element.text());    
}
```